# How to show DateTime.Now.ToString(Format("yyyy")) incrimental in for loop

Tags: vb.net

![enter image description here][1]In windows Application I want to Show a datagridview in which year column I want to show year in incremental by 1 i.e. 2014, 2015 etc by using  for Loop

```
Public Class Form1


Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'Init.
    ' Set up the Header Color and Font.
    With DataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle
        .Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
        .BackColor = Color.DarkRed
        .ForeColor = Color.Gold
        .Font = New Font(.Font.FontFamily, .Font.Size, _
         .Font.Style Or FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Point)
    End With


End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Try


    ' Fill in some Text.

    '
    '   Code for First Row
    '

    Dim Bonus = TextBox2.Text * 0.001 * ComboBox2.SelectedItem
    Dim SA = TextBox2.Text
    Dim NormalCover = TextBox2.Text + Bonus
    Dim Dab = 2 * SA
    Dim AccBenefit = Dab + Bonus
    Dim Premium = TextBox4.Text
    Dim TaxRebate = Premium * ComboBox1.SelectedItem * 0.01
    Dim NetOutgo = Premium - TaxRebate
    Dim YlyReturn = 0

    Dim arrStrings As String()
    arrStrings = New String() _
     { _
         DateTime.Now.ToString(Format("yyyy")), TextBox1.Text.ToString, NormalCover.ToString, _
    AccBenefit.ToString, Premium.ToString, CStr(Math.Round(TaxRebate)), CStr(Math.Round(NetOutgo)), YlyReturn.ToString _
     }
    DataGridView1.Rows.Add(arrStrings)
    arrStrings = Nothing

    '
    '  Code for second to  second last Row
    '


        For i As Integer = 0 To TextBox3.Text - 2

            TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text + 1
            NormalCover = NormalCover + Bonus
            AccBenefit = AccBenefit + Bonus


            arrStrings = New String() _
             { _
           DateTime.Now.ToString(Format("yyyy")).ToString, TextBox1.Text.ToString, NormalCover.ToString, _
             AccBenefit.ToString, Premium.ToString, CStr(Math.Round(TaxRebate)), CStr(Math.Round(NetOutgo)), YlyReturn.ToString _
             }
            DataGridView1.Rows.Add(arrStrings)
            arrStrings = Nothing
        Next i

        '
        '  Code for Last Row
        '

        TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text + 1
        NormalCover = NormalCover + Bonus

        AccBenefit = AccBenefit + Bonus
        YlyReturn = TextBox2.Text + Bonus * TextBox3.Text
        arrStrings = New String() _
         { _
         DateTime.Now.ToString(Format("yyyy")), TextBox1.Text.ToString, NormalCover.ToString, _
        AccBenefit.ToString, Premium.ToString, CStr(Math.Round(TaxRebate)), CStr(Math.Round(NetOutgo)), YlyReturn.ToString _
         }
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add(arrStrings)
        arrStrings = Nothing

        '
        '  Code for Summary Row
        '

        Premium = Premium * TextBox3.Text
        TaxRebate = TaxRebate * TextBox3.Text
        NetOutgo = Premium - TaxRebate
        arrStrings = New String() _
         { _
         "Total".ToString, "-".ToString, "-".ToString, _
        "-".ToString, Premium.ToString, CStr(Math.Round(TaxRebate)), CStr(Math.Round(NetOutgo)), "-".ToString _
         }
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add(arrStrings)
        arrStrings = Nothing
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_Leave(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Leave
    If Not IsNumeric(TextBox1.Text) Then TextBox1.Focus()
    If Val(TextBox1.Text) < 0 Then
        TextBox1.BackColor = Color.Red
    Else
        TextBox1.BackColor = Color.White

    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

how to show that pl any can explain.

Comment: What on earth are you asking?

Comment: Is this what you want?: `For y As Integer = Date.Now.Year To (Date.Now.Year + 1)`

Comment: I want year in datagridview showing year as incrimental by 1 i.e 2014, 2015 etc in column using Forloop

Comment: @sunilsb Then why did you say `In windows Application`? You need to be as *specific* as possible. We cannot read you mind. (And that's a good thing right?) Include all relevant details and code.

Comment: sure I shall always try for that

Comment: @sunilsb Great! I've voted for reopening. Please consider adding more details to the question. I still think it's a bit vague. Do you want `a column` or `multiple columns`? Like `[2014][2015][2016]`. Vital information should be added to the question (by editing), not as a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a loop to generate a series of years starting at the current year then you should do something like this:

```
For i = 0 To 10
    Dim year = Date.Now.Year + i

    '...
Next
```

Running that code now would give you a series of `Integer` values from 2014 to 2024 inclusive, to do with whatever you like.